# Multidimensional array - get value of each element at same time

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, multidimensional-array

Having issue creating the logic for this. Is it even possible ?

Let’s say you have

```
Var one = [[1,1,1]]
Var two = [[2,2,2]]
Var three = [[3,3,3]]

Var k = [one,two,three]
```

Assume you won’t know the length of var “k”.

I’m trying to write a function that will allow me to access all elements in “k” at the same time and access each index value.

Example.

```
k[0][0]
k[1][0]
k[2][0]
——————
k[0][1]
k[1][1]
k[2][1]
——————
```

I know for loops is a start but I’m stuck when it comes to accessing each element at the same time Dynamically. Is this even possible ?

Comment: What do you mean with `accessing each element at the same time dynamically`?

Comment: Will `one`, `two` and `three` ever have more than one array within them? If not, there is very little point making them an array of arrays, as just an array would suffice.

Comment: Yes , one two and three will have more then one element in them. @Chris

Comment: What I mean by access them at the same time is I want to access the index of the values of each element at the same time. Instead of waiting for the for loop to finish looping through one element before moving on to the other. I want all elements to be accessed at the same time

Comment: @TenkorangDarko So you want something that would lost all the values along with the three index integers required to get them?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to build a 3 x 3 matrix you can write

```
var one = [1,1,1]
var two = [2,2,2]
var three = [3,3,3]
var k = [one, two, three]
```

Now you have in memory the equivalent of this matrix

```
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3
```

And you can access an element using this syntax

```
k[i][j]
```

where `i` and `j` are integers between `0` and `2`.

Example

```
k[0][0] // 1
```

> If you are looking for a good way to work with a matrix have a look here https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html#subscripts

Comment: What I want is a print out of all the elements index value at the same time. So I would want “1,2,3”

Answer (score 0):

Rather than working directly against the 2D array I wrapped it in a struct `Matrix` where the function `column(at:)` will return all values in a column. The struct is generic to allow for different element types

```
struct Matrix<T> {
    private var data: [[T]]

    private init() {
        data = []
    }

    init(rows: [T]...) {
        self.init()
        let check = rows.first?.count ?? 0
        for row in rows {
            guard row.count == check else { fatalError("All rows must be the same length")}
            data.append(row)
        }
    }

    func row(at index: Int) -> [T]? {
        guard index < data.count else { return nil }

        return data[index]
    }

    func column(at index: Int) -> [T]? {
        guard !data.isEmpty else { return nil }

        var column = [T]()

        for i in 0..<data.count {
            column.append(data[i][index])
        }

        return column
    }
}
```

And it can be used like this

```
let matrix = Matrix(rows: [1,1,2],[2,2,2],[3,3,3])
print(matrix.column(at: 1))
print(matrix.row(at: 1))

let matrix2 = Matrix(rows: ["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"],["g", "h"])
print(matrix2.column(at: 1))
print(matrix2.row(at: 1))
```

> [1, 2, 3]
>   [2, 2, 2]
>   ["b", "d", "f", "h"]
>   ["c", "d"]